# Show Listbox if checkboxlist item selected is in linq result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to find the correct code-behind to display a listbox IF one or more certain checkboxlist items are selected. The checkboxlist is created from an entity data source, and the SQL table of that source also has a field that indicates if that selection should show the listbox. Whew! The table looks like this:

```
GUID grade_level show_college_list
(gen)    12           0 (bit)
(gen)  College        1
```

The asp is such:

```
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="GradeLevelEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=NewCourseRequestDataEntities" 
            DefaultContainerName="NewCourseRequestDataEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
            EntitySetName="grade_levels" OrderBy="it.grade_level_description">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" cssClass="leftlabel" runat="server" text="Grade Level (check all that apply):"></asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="GradeLevelCheckBoxList" runat="server" cssClass="horizontalcontrols"
            DataSourceID="GradeLevelEntityDataSource" 
            DataTextField="grade_level_description" DataValueField="grade_level_id" AutoPostBack="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="CollegeInstitutionsListboxChange"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

If College is checked, I want the Institutions listbox panel should show.
This is how far I've gotten on the code:

```
       if (sender != null)
            {
                foreach (ListItem grade in GradeLevelCheckBoxList.Items)
                {
                    if (grade.Selected == true)
                    {
                        NewCourseRequestDataEntities context = new NewCourseRequestDataEntities();
                        var guids = from g in context.grade_levels where g.show_college_list == true select g;

                        if ( guids.Contains(new Guid(grade.Value)) )
                        {
                            testselected.Text = grade.Value; //for testing
                            CollegeInstitutionsSelectPanel.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm receiving these 2 errors on the contains method. I don't know what they mean.

Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'   Y:\visual studio\New Course Request\NewCourseRequestForm.aspx.cs    146 34  New Course Request

Error   2   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments   Y:\visual studio\New Course Request\NewCourseRequestForm.aspx.cs    146 34  New Course Request

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Based on these errors, there's more code involved. I'm guessing there's a AsParallel() call somewhere, for example. Can you reproduce the behavior using Linq to Objects with a static array?

Comment: What method is this code example in?

Answer (score 0):

Try ( for Error2- I don't understand where the Error1 is coming from...):

```
if(guids.Where(x=>x==new Guid(grade.Value)).FirstOrDefault()!=null)
{
     //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it --

```
     NewCourseRequestDataEntities context = new NewCourseRequestDataEntities();
     var guids = (from g in context.grade_levels where g.show_college_list == true select g**.grade_level_id**).ToList();

                        bool contains = guids.Contains(new Guid(grade.Value));
                        if (contains)
                        {
                            CollegeInstitutionsSelectPanel.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CollegeInstitutionsSelectPanel.Visible = false;
                        }
```

I hadn't specified the Guid field in the table. I had '*select g*' SHOULD have had '*select g.grade_level_id*' (which is the Guid field). No sure if I need the ToList...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (slight modification to .Where(...) answer):

`foo.Visible = guids.Any(x=>x==new Guid(grade.Value)`